# Find and replace match in first column

Tags: bash

I have a CSV file that I would like to make bulk changes on column 1.

If V change to Outbound and if N change to Inbound

```
Call Type   Call Cause  Customer Identifier Telephone Number Dialled    Call Date   Call 
N       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:59:09    53
N       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:55:44    264
V       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:55:16    295
N       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:59:02    70
N       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:52:40    453
V       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:59:32    41
N       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:28:21    1915
```

I think AWK might be the tool for the job but I'm not how to achieve this and will be using this on linux.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the field separator of your CSV?

Comment: "N","1","1111","111","15/12/2022",

separated by a comma

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of awk you should use sed for this: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

For example, this would output the file with all the N's (at the beginning of each line) changed to "Inbound":

```
sed 's+^N+Inbound+g' calls.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1=="V" {$1="Outbound"} $1=="N" {$1="Inbound"} {print}' first.csv
```

Where `first.csv` is your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Use an inline if/else to set the first column (`$1`) to a new value, then `print` the whole row:

```
 awk -F '[[:space:]]' '{ $1 = ($1 == "N" ? "Inbound" : "Outbound"); print $0; }' inputfile.txt
```

```
Inbound       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:59:09    53
Inbound       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:55:44    264
Outbound       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:55:16    295
Inbound       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:59:02    70
Inbound       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:52:40    453
Outbound       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:59:32    41
Inbound       2       1           1               15/12/2022  10:28:21    1915
```